# use of two will's in the same sentence

Tags: tense

I have made up the example below.

(1) I am very excited about next month. That **will** be the first time I **will** go skydiving.

Is it okay to use the future tense "will" twice in the second sentence?

Answer (score 3):

It would be more natural to say 'That will be the first time I go skydiving' - omitting the second 'will'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.